# Logstash http_poller only shows last logmessage in Kibana

Tags: logstash, kibana

I am using Logstash to get the log from a url using http_poller. This works fine. The problem I have is that the log that gets received does not get send to Elastic Search in the right way. I tried splitting the result in different events but the only event that shows in Kibana is the last event from the log. Since I am pulling the log every 2 minutes, a lot of log information gets lost this way.

The input is like this:

```
input {
  http_poller {
    urls => {
        logger1 => {
            method => get
            url => "http://servername/logdirectory/thislog.log"
        }

    }
    keepalive => true
    automatic_retries => 0
    # Check the site every 2 minutes
    interval => 120
    request_timeout => 110
    # Wait no longer than 110 seconds for the request to complete
    # Store metadata about the request in this field
    metadata_target => http_poller_metadata
    type => 'log4j' 
    codec => "json"

    # important tag settings
    tags => stackoverflow
  }
}
```

I then use a filter to add some fields and to split the logs

```
filter { 
if "stackoverflow" in [tags] {

    split { 
        terminator => "\n" 
    }
    mutate  {
        add_field => { 
            "Application" => "app-stackoverflow" 
            "Environment" => "Acceptation" 
        }
    }
}
}
```

The output then gets send to the Kibana server using the following output conf

```
output {
   redis { 
    host => "kibanaserver.internal.com" 
    data_type => "list" 
key => "logstash N" 
   }
 }
```

Any suggestions why not all the events are stored in Kibana?